# Allowed memory size exhausted in module-aws-s3/Driver/AwsS3Factory.php on line 46

Tags: magento2, aws, memory, memory-limit

While Running cache:flush command I am Facing strange error like this,

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 4294967296 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in public_html/vendor/magento/module-aws-s3/Driver/AwsS3Factory.php on line 46

even if Memory limit is set to -1 I am getting this error

Any solution ?

Comment: What's your php.ini "memory_limit"?

Comment: memory limit in php.ini is 4GB

Comment: Try running this command: "php -d memory_limit=2048M bin/magento c:f"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its the error of AWS toolkit

Just Install It :

```
composer require aws/aws-sdk-php
```

Now try to run command cache:flush Its working

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with your AWS S3 Bucket storage. See this guide how to increase.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/remote-storage/config-remote-storage-aws-s3.html